# Animating a Fragment / Activity only one side on the screen, as in the new Google Maps

Tags: android, android-fragments

Recently Google Maps has been updated to the Material Design.

I'm interested in doing something like he did to animate a Fragment / Activity only one side of the screen.

**How to do this?**

[image: Clicking in blue button ...]

[image: Animate only one side]

Comment: can you please explain what actually are you trying to do ...

Comment: I have a screen exactly like that, with a lot of information in place of this map. I also have a Floating Action Button on the right side and want to display another screen, only on one side, when this button is clicked, just as is done in the maps.